# What are the advantages of a $ SKU of VS2012 over Express?

Tags: c#, windows-8, xaml, resharper

I will be using Visual Studio only for creating C#/XAML Windows Store apps. Is there any reason for me to purchase a "Professional" SKU of VS 2012 rather than just using the Express (free) "Metro apps with C#/XAML" version?

The only thing I can think of is that I won't be able to use Resharper in the Express version (which I've already purchased a license for, but I use it at work, so that won't be a waste of money if I can't use it at home) - plus, I believe that even the Express SKU of VS 2012 will have similar code quality utility built in.

Comment: Exact Duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7431409/visual-studio-2010-express-limitations (But that is on SO)

Comment: Those deal with VS2010 and even further back; I'm specifically asking about VS2012. Even the Wikipedia article (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio_Express) does not cover VS2012 yet.

Comment: What exactly is your question?  The differences between Visual Studio Express and any of the paid versions is outline on Microsoft's website.  One major difference between the paid version and the express versions is the platform support, support for desktop applications are different, but that doesn't appear to be important to you.

Comment: @ClayShannon - Actually it does. Feel free to compare the editions yourself on Microsoft's visual studio website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcbsd3cz(v=vs.80).aspx

Basically no mobile device support, no class diagram support, Database design tools (local only)

No way to develop visual studios packages, or deploy those packages, No 64 bit integration or SQL 2005 support.

So, I'd recommend getting a Visual Studios Professional MSDN account!

Hope the link helps.

Comment: The question is about VS 2012, why are you linking to a page about VS 2005?